# When is two way binding for services injected into controller resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I am trying to understand why the following code will only log

```
Array []
Array [object, object]
```

When I submit the form while I expect

```
Array [object, object]
Array [object, object]
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b5a9dd7634ee97bc01cf

Shouldn't

```
$scope.posts.push({
        title: $scope.title,
        link: $scope.link, 
        upvotes: 0
    });
```

Immediately update the service?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks

```
angular.module('flapperNews', [])
  .factory('postsFactory', [function(){
    // Modularize posts frontend storage for better mock testing and independency of scope
    var posts_factory_object = {
        posts_list: []
    };
    return posts_factory_object;
  }])
  .controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'postsFactory',
    function($scope, postsFactory){

      // Bind scope.posts to postsFactory.posts_list
      $scope.posts = postsFactory.posts_list;

      // Variable pseudo post data for test
      $scope.posts = [
        {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},

      ];

      // Frontend function for keeping track of state purely in frontend
      $scope.addPost = function(){
        // Check if inputted string is undefinied or empty
        if (!$scope.title || $scope.title ===''){ return; }

        $scope.posts.push({
            title: $scope.title,
            link: $scope.link, 
            upvotes: 0
        });
        $scope.title = '';
        $scope.link = '';

        console.log(postsFactory.posts_list);
        console.log($scope.posts);
      };


    }]);
```

Comment: Any of the below answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Your service did not get updates because you are overwriting the reference of the service object `postsFactory.posts_list` held by `$scope.posts` with another array by doing:

```
 $scope.posts = [
    {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},
  ];
```

So any changes made to `$scope.posts` will not be reflected in the object in the service since they both point to different reference. You can verify that by doing:-

```
 $scope.posts.push({title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5});
```

As long as both the properties holds the same reference you will be able see the changes reflected on the either side.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $scope.posts = postsFactory.posts_list;
```

Is not the same as creating a binding. You are actually just setting the **reference value** of $scope.posts to be postsFactory.posts_list. Then you immediately overwrite this reference using

```
  // Variable pseudo post data for test
  $scope.posts = [
    {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},

  ];
```

So now $scope.posts is an entirely different list. postFactory.posts_list is orphaned, and will not be updated in the addPost function.

Have a read about AngularJS watchers, that is what you're really interested in here.

Additionally, two-way databinding is typically added by binding things in templates (at least for beginners) - using ng-bind or the {{bindme}} syntax